# Canvas gets resized automatically

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to develop a canvas element where users can drop uploaded images. However, I am running into trouble with this command

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasID');
```

The canvas element is somehow getting resized and I don't understand why. Can anyone help?

Comment: could you add a bit of a context? what is this code, where does it run? how do you notice the canvas element is being resized, through firebug, with your eyes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding the canvas is resizing to a size smaller than you expected, there is a good chance you haven't defined the height and width of the canvas itself when creating it with Fabric.

An example of doing this would be:

```
var id = 'c',
drawingMode = true,
w = 1024,
h = 768,
newCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(id, { isDrawingMode: drawingMode });
newCanvas.setWidth(w);
newCanvas.setHeight(h);
```

The variables w and h are just examples, but the last two lines ensure your canvas has a size set rather than default of 300 x 150.

Hope this helps.